# In mysql I see different response time from different partition in same table

Tags: mysql, database, performance, partition

Mysql version: 5.6

I have a table having 20 million records. Primary key of the table is bigint with auto-increment on. I use range partition on id column:

```
partition by Range (ID) (
  partition p0 values less than (5000000),
  partition p1 values less than (10000000),
  partition p2 values less than (15000000),
  partition p3 values less than (20000000),
  partition p4 values less than (25000000),
  partition p5 values less than MAXVALUE
);
```

During bench marking, I select 1000 items from each partition using IN clause--

```
SElECT * from t_b WHERE ID in ( 6000, 1000, 499000, 91000, ... );
```

I have a script to generate this IN clause. These 1000 items are evenly distributed in this partition and in random order .  Above query only picks partition p0.  I verified with 'explain partitions ...'.

I thought the response time will be similar when I query on different partition.  I made sure each query only includes 1000 items from  same partition.

The query result surprises me:

```
 [p0] 1.5 seconds,   
 [p1] 1.3 seconds, 
 [p2] 0.28 seconds, 
 [p3] 0.06 seconds.
```

It looks like the later the partition (records are newer in terms of timestamp), the faster responds.
The engine is innodb.  The result does not change much when I choose different buffer_pool_size. ( 1G, 500Meg, 250Meg).

I turned off query cache.
   In order to remove the impact of buffer_pool between running different queries, I run query on different partition intentionally in sequence.  Such as first query run on p1, second query run on p4, then p2 ...

I run 20+ tests and above response time on different partition is very consistent.

I am confused what is the reason response time is different on different partition.

-------- new edit:

```
buffer_pool_dump is disabled.
 read ahead is disabled.
 Additional status check after running sql on one partition,then restart mysql:

 [p0] 0.8-0.9 seconds
 [p1] 0.7-0.8 seconds
 [p2] 1 - 1.2 seconds
 [p3] 0.06 seconds  

 p0

Handler_read_first      17
Handler_read_key        1025
Handler_read_last       0
Handler_read_next       0
Handler_read_prev       0
Handler_read_rnd        0
Handler_read_rnd_next   585
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_rnd       0
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead   0
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_evicted   0
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests        7902
Innodb_buffer_pool_reads        1548

-----------------------------

p1

Handler_read_first      17
Handler_read_key        1025
Handler_read_last       0
Handler_read_next       0
Handler_read_prev       0
Handler_read_rnd        0
Handler_read_rnd_next   585
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_rnd       0
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead   0
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_evicted   0
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests        7951
Innodb_buffer_pool_reads        1571

-----------------------------

p2

Handler_read_first      17
Handler_read_key        1025
Handler_read_last       0
Handler_read_next       0
Handler_read_prev       0
Handler_read_rnd        0
Handler_read_rnd_next   585
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_rnd       0
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead   0
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_evicted   0
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests        7900
Innodb_buffer_pool_reads        1547


-----------------------------

p3

Handler_read_first      3
Handler_read_key        997
Handler_read_last       0
Handler_read_next       0
Handler_read_prev       0
Handler_read_rnd        0
Handler_read_rnd_next   585
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_rnd       0
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead   0
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_evicted   0
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests        7632
Innodb_buffer_pool_reads        1558
```

Comment: Could you please turn off buffer pool dumping. Restart mysql and do the following test for each partition: 1) run test 2) mysql -e 'show global status' | grep -e Handler_read -e Innodb_buffer_pool_read 3) restart mysql. Do you use read ahead?

Comment: ravnur thanks for your reply. The comment area is too small so I add test result in the original post. In [p3] test, Handler_read_rnd_next is much smaller than other three tests.

Comment: ravnur.  After I repeat tests a few times.  In [p3] test, I can see Handler_read_rnd_next count is 585  , that is same as other partitions.  With restarting mysql between each test, I can see response time for [p0] is 0.8-0.9 seconds, [p1] is 0.8s, [p2] is 1-1.2 seconds [p3] is consistently 0.06 seconds.

Comment: Are you generating a different set of random ids for each test?  Double check that they really are different, and not differing by small amounts.  It smells like you happened to get better caching of P3.  In particular, why is `Handler_read_rnd_next` so much lower?

Comment: Rick, I use shell script:     for i in {1..999}; do echo `expr $i \\* 5000 + 15002194` >> ids.txt;done;  to generate test ids.  This example is for [p3]. Each id is 5000 apart, they share same base of 15,000,000 + a  number I random select in each data generation. They are evenly distributed in one partition.

Comment: Rick, I am not sure why the Handler_read_rnd_next in one of my test for [P3] is so low. After I repeated multiple times,  I noticed that account was consistent with other p0-p2 tests ==> 585.  I update original post to avoid confusion.